# Story where Oppenheimer literally becomes the Angel of Death

Tags: story-identification

I recall very little about this story, not even how long it was or when I might have read it.

It is based on the real-world event when Robert Oppenheimer, after the first nuclear bomb test explosion at Trinity, quoted the Bhagavad Gita saying "I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds."

However, in this world which up to this point was essentially ours, some supernatural forces are unleashed by the explosion of the atomic bomb.  One notable effect of which is that Oppenheimer is *literally* turned into the Angel of Death.

One of the people in the story makes a remark to the effect of "Shame about what happened to Oppenheimer."

Comment: Did Kenneth Bainbridge's mother turn into a dog?

Comment: @Buzz That doesn't seem like something I remember. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be the Cthulhu Mythos short story ["The Unthinkable"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47733) by Bruce Sterling? It is set in an alternate history where World War II was fought with Lovecraftian supernatural weaponry like the Azathoth Bomb.

Quotation:

> “‘I am become Death, the Destroyer of Worlds,’” Tsyganov quoted.
>
> “Yeah,” Doughty mused. “That was too bad about poor old Oppy having to
> become Death.”

The story can be read in the August 1991 edition of *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* on the Internet Archive - [link](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v081n02_1991-08/page/n95/mode/2up).

Comment: Oh, very nice, that's definitely it.  Somewhere I have the Sterling collection *Globalhead* which is where I would have read it.